# one-to-many relationship Node Js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm trying to select all of the photos from the currently logged in user based on their session_id.

I have a photos table that keeps track of the pictures that belong to each user.

id |
user_photos |
user_id (Foreign Key)

```
let select_photos_sql = "SELECT * FROM photos WHERE user_id = ?";
mysql_connection.query(select_photos_sql, [session_id], function (error, rows) {

    if(error){
        res.send("An error has occurred, please try again later.");
    } else {

        if(rows.length > 0){ /**IS THIS BLOCK NECESSARY? WHEN I CHANGE IT TO === 1, I DON'T GET THE 
                                ERROR BUT I GET NO PHOTOS FOUND**/

            rows.forEach(function (row) {

                let photos = row.user_photos;

                console.log(photos); /**LOGS OUT THE PHOTOS FROM THE USER BUT CAN'T DISPLAY IT**/

                res.render("user_photos", {photos: photos});
            });


        } else {
            res.send("No photos found.");
        }

    }

   });
```

When I run the code, I keep getting this error message "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client." What am I doing wrong? Do I need to join the users table here? Any help will greatly be appreciated.

Comment: try putting `res.render` out of your loop

Answer (score 0):

"Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client." means you are trying to send more that one response to user, use can use this function

```
res.json(rows.map(function (row) { return row.user_photos }))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not send a response from a loop, because it sends a response for the first time and after that, it gives the error.
Please try this-

```
let select_photos_sql = "SELECT * FROM photos WHERE user_id = ?";
 mysql_connection.query(select_photos_sql, [session_id], function (error, 
rows) {
if(error){
    res.send("An error has occurred, please try again later.");
} else {

    if(rows.length > 0){ /**IS THIS BLOCK NECESSARY? WHEN I CHANGE IT TO === 1, I DON'T GET THE 
                            ERROR BUT I GET NO PHOTOS FOUND**/
        var photos_arr = [];
        var photo_count = 0;
        rows.forEach(function (row) {

            let photos = row.user_photos;

            console.log(photos); /**LOGS OUT THE PHOTOS FROM THE USER BUT CAN'T DISPLAY IT**/
            photos_arr.push(photos);
            photo_count = photo_count+1;
        });
        if (photo_count == rows.length) {
            res.render("user_photos", {photos: photos_arr});
        }

    } else {
        res.send("No photos found.");
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked! By any chance, do you know how I can output the user's images in an html image tag? I have an image tag on my .ejs file, but when it outputs the result it outputs as: image1, image2. Then if I place an image tag with the result in the src, it will be <img src="image1,image2" />. Is there a way where I can get it to <img src="image1" /> <img src="image2" /> Perhaps some type of loop?